# How to insert an extra character in a string in C

Tags: c, string, character, addition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void replace(char a[],char b[]);

int main(void)
{
    char string1[100]; char string2[100];
    printf("Please enter a string:");
    fgets(string1, sizeof(string1), stdin);

    replace(string1, string2);
}

void replace(char a[],char b[])
{
    int i;
    strcpy(b,a);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
    {
        if(a[i]=='a')
        {
            b[i+1]=a[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n",b);
}
```

The function of this program is to copy `string1` into `string2` but if there's any `'a'` character in `string1`, it needed to be double in `string2`.

For example, if `string1` is "aeroplane", the `string2` needs to be "aaeroplaane".

However, the code above seem to change the next character after `'a'` in `string1` instead of simply adding it. For example, if I type "aloha", it will simply give me "aaoha" instead of "aalohaa". I've tried searching online but to no avail. I've been sticking on this problem for hours.

Comment: `the code above seem to change the next character after 'a' in string1 instead of simply adding it.` It does because that's what you have coded there

Comment: Hint: You need two index variables (i and j).

Comment: Yea but I can't seem to figure how to add the character without deleting the next character...

Comment: @k'hng you don't delete anything,your're copying.

Comment: You need to insert the character into the string, not over write the next character. Def read PhillipD's helpful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to work you must implement your `replace` function correctly

It should be like:

```
void replace(char a[],char b[])
{
    int idxA = 0, idxB = 0;

    for(idxA;idxA<strlen(a);idxA++, idxB++)
   {
        b[idxB] = a[idxA];
        if(a[idxA]=='a')
        {
            idxB++;
            b[idxB]=a[idxA];
        }
    }

    b[idxB] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",b);
}
```

But you must ensure `b` has enough space to hold the complete string. For example, you can reserve twice the size of `a`, the worst case when array `a` has all `a` characters

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if we are playing code golf, I would suggest:

```
void replace (char *a, char *b) {
        while ((*b++ = *a)) 
                if (*a++ == 'a')
                        *b++ = 'a';
}
```

;)

Mind to provide enough memory in `b`; if you want to play it safe, it has to be at least `strlen(a)*2+1` (the case `a` consists only of character "a").

Comment: I'll look into this and try to implement this in my code . Thank you!

Comment: `((*b++ = *a))` -> `(*b++ = *a)` if we're playing code golf

Comment: @Bathsheba eat this: `while((*b++=*a)&&((*a++!='a')||(*b++='a')));`

Comment: @Ctx: If you put that as an answer, I'll upvote both.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't dare to ;))

Comment: @Batsheba ok, you asked for it ;)

Comment: Made one correction (took out a pair of redundant parentheses), and a comment golf of my own.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of brevity and elegance, here's a one liner:

```
void replace (char *a, char *b) { while((*b++=*a)&&(*a++!='a'||(*b++='a'))); }
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

with

```
b[i+1]=a[i]
```

you're changing the next character to be 'a' and overwriting the next character.
What should be done is moving all the characters after b[i+1] one step forward and then changing 'a' in b[i+a]

Answer (score 0):

I wont solve it for you.
But here is what you need to look into.

```
if(a[i]=='a')
{
    b[i+1]=a[i];
}
```

What it is doing is, if `i`th index of `a` array is `'a'` then write `i`th index of `a` array in `i+1`th location of array `b`.

This way you are over-writing the contents of `b`.
You need to make a place for an additional character there **only after shifting** the string from that index to right.
It can be done in multiple ways.

Additionally, you might want to allocate more size (ideally twice: To cover the case when you pass a `string1` with 100 `'a'`s, the resulting `string2` should hold 200 `'a'`s) to your second array than the first one, because of obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes , you're right. I've should have double the size of string2 incase there's a 100 'a' in string1. Thank you for giving such good insight.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void replace(char a[], char b[]);

int main(void)
{
  char string1[100]; char string2[100];
  printf("Please enter a string:");
  fgets(string1, sizeof(string1), stdin);

  replace(string1, string2);

  printf("%s\n", string2);      // printf result from replace here
}


void replace(char a[], char b[])
{
  int i, j;   // using two indexes, one for a and one for b

              // no strcpy needed here, copying is done in the for loop below       

  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(a); i++, j++)
  {
    b[j] = a[i];        // copy one char

    if (a[i] == 'a')    // if it's 'a'
    {
      b[++j] = a[i];    // copy it again
    }
  }

  b[j] = 0;             // terminate the destination string
                        // we don't printf b here but in main
}
```

For brevity no buffer overflow checking is done here.

There is still room for improvement though.

Answer (score 0):

```
void replace(char a[],char b[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(a); i++, j++)
    {
        b[j] = a[i];
        if(a[i] == 'a')
            b[++j] = a[i];
    }
}
```

see if this works.